# Install msi file with PowerShell v3.0

Tags: windows-installer, powershell-3.0

I am trying to automatically install SharePoint 2013 and for this I have to install a MSI file with PowerShell but it returns an error when I execute it.

This is the error message:

> Error: This command cannot be run due to the error: No application is
>   associated with the specified file for this operation.

Here is the command I'm trying to execute..

```
Start-Process -FilePath C:\SharePoint_V2\SQL Shared Features\SQLSysClrTypes.msi -ArgumentList /qn /quiet /norestart /l* C:\temp\SQLCLR.log -WorkingDirectory C:\SharePoint_V2\SQL Shared Features\ -verb runAs -Wait;
```

This is what I've tried/checked:

- I can install the msi manually (so there is an application associated with the specified file)
- the default program to open an msi file is set to Windows Installer
- script is been run as administrator

I have been searching for a solution for a couple of hours now and I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would call msiexec directly and include the /I-switch (that's an i and not L) in the argumentlist.
(Check `msiexec /?` on the command line for full options)

In your case it would be something like the example below. Please take note to the double quotes around the full argumentlist.

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/I C:\SharePoint_V2\SQL Shared Features\SQLSysClrTypes.msi /qn /quiet /norestart /l* C:\temp\SQLCLR.log" -WorkingDirectory C:\SharePoint_V2\SQL Shared Features\ -verb runAs -Wait;
```

Comment: Thanks. With a few tweaks I was able to make it work. I still had a few errors due to the fact that I was trying to concatenate within the Start-Process.

Final result:
`Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList $SQLCLRArgumentList -WorkingDirectory $SharedFeaturesPath -verb runAs -Wait;`